# Associate different Google Chrome profiles with different virtual desktops

Tags: macos, google-chrome, spaces

I usually work in several Google Chrome profiles (like "My working me" and "My procrastinating me") and I prefer to keep those **windows on different "virtual desktops"**. So, every time my laptop boot up, I spend few minutes on "dragging" windows at their destined screens. I know that I can "pin" specific apps to specific desktops by using "Options > This desktop" and it works great.

But I'm yet to figure out how to "fine tune" this feature for distinguishing between **different Chrome windows** (by Chrome profile). Is it possible at all?

Comment: Spaces is designed to be "one app, one Space". There's no good way round this. I'd be tempted to use different browsers, or different Mac accounts, whichever is least inconvenient.

Comment: I've had the same question in the past. The closest I was able to come was to have one profile in Google Chrome and another in Chromium.

Comment: I think I'll try and install Chrome Canary and usi it for one of profiles.